# error in Custome class with required and not required fields

Tags: flutter

I am creating a class where I want some fields to be required and some not required but I am getting an error and it forced me to make it required where I don't require it

I have made simple demo to explain my problem...

where I want to make a container with gesturedetector and a text ..Text is required but don't want to make required function

feeling bad that I am failing to solve such simple coding...

here is my coding

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'mybutton.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body:Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

            children: [
             MyButton(txt: 'red',function: (){
               print('red is clicked');
             }),
              MyButton(txt: 'Green'),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my custome class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String txt;
  final VoidCallback function;

   MyButton({required this.txt, this.function});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: function,
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Text(txt,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,color: Colors.green),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart enforces you all the time, to have non null values for all of your variables, **unless** they are marked as nullable.

Changing your code to this, will fix your issue:

```dart
  final VoidCallback? function;
```

The question mark tells Dart, that your `function` variable can have a null value, hence the constructor will work as it currently is.